# ASP.NET Core MVC doesn't launch on default route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For some weird reason, it launches to https://localhost:44397/index.html instead of going to the Index method in my home controller. I don't have an index.html file in wwwroot so I don't know why this weird behaviour is occuring.

I just want to have normal behaviour which is launch directly to Index when URL is like this https://localhost:44397/ .

I have some other API controllers if this helps however I've done it numerous times before so I don't suspect it's what's causing this issue.I also tried creating a new MVC project and running directly and stock template worked fine. Any help would be immensely appreciated, thanks.

I have a home controller which looks like this

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

my Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

           // CreateRoles(serviceProvider);
        }
```

launchSetting.json file

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64858",
      "sslPort": 44397
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    },
    "IcartE1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you starting your project?

Comment: IIS Express @MaartenDev

Comment: Wait do you use the open action from IIS management tool? Or do you run it from Visual Studio?

Comment: I run from visual studio @MaartenDev

Comment: Did you try configuring the `launchUrl` property of the `IIS Express` profile?

Comment: I tried setting launchUrl to "home" which indeed launches the View at Index() however using any anchor tag helpers on the view with asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" still redirects me to index.html so there's still something wrong

Comment: How does the generated URL look in the html source?

Comment: href="/" @MaartenDev

Comment: Ah then IIS redirects / to index.html, did you try modifying the default document through IIS management? Did you try creating a controller on a different route then `/`? Something like `/example`?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, for me it was the browser that caches the redirect urls. So if you push f12 and select the (Empty Cache and Hard Reload). It will clear it and stop routing you to index.html

ore read through this
https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define AddControllers dependency injection, so in ConfigureServices method add this line:

```
services.AddControllers();
```

After that, add this route to Endpoints middleware parameters:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem I had, about browser caching

You may check the answers from this link:
[Weird redirection problem with ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72668139/weird-redirection-problem-with-asp-net-core-6-razor-pages-application)