# Weird redirection problem with ASP.NET Core 6 Razor pages application

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

When I run the application application redirects to the `/dashboard` page instead of `/index` page.

It's weird because that application don't a page with that name and no redirection code to that page. I checked `index.cshtml`, `index.cshtml.cs`, `_layout.cshtml`, `program.cs` and also searched solution wide for page name `dashboard`.

But it's also weird and confusing another project in another solution has this redirection.

How this can be? Am I missing some point? That is very annoying.

project 1 launchsettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:39662",
      "sslPort": 44359
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Yoneticim.EmailProviders.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7179;http://localhost:5179",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

project 2 launchsettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:39662",
      "sslPort": 44359
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Fabrikafa.CC.Web": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7178;http://localhost:5178",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the related part of startup.cs

```
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dies it happen when you run it on local machine mode?

Comment: did you check the lunchsettings.json in the properties folder? the application follows the file at startup

Comment: @GuruStron yes it is. This happens on my local development machine

Comment: @ParsaS i checked the file on both projets. Also tried changing the port info of one of them. I will post the lauchsettings file contents to the top

Comment: that's okay, I can't see any problem here

Comment: @ParsaS yes, there is no problem.

Comment: What middleware do you add in Startup.cs?

Comment: Is there a /swagger?

Comment: Try in another browser. I’ve found chrome aggressively caches some redirects so you may need to remove your temporary internet files.

Comment: Yes there is but i dont think that is the case @RetroCoder, did you had a smillar issue?

Comment: @Alan Macdonald I added my startup file to the top.

Comment: @nfplee using firefox but when I tried with chrome redirection did not occur.

Comment: @OzanBAYRAM sounds like Firefox is caching the redirect the same. It's a really annoying problem. I'm glad that helped.